# How can I encode a query string with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string

I want to redirect

```
http://myoldsite.com/page?query=some+arguments&some_more
```

To

```
'http://mynewsite.com/?notfound=' + urlencode('page?query=some+arguments&some_more')
```

Is this possible with htaccess alone?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`B` and NE flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html) to **escape** the back-references:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^page/?$ /?notfound=$0\%3f%0 [L,NC,R=302,B,NE]
```

Comment: That sounds promising - I hadn't realized NE and B could be combined. What would the result be without B here?

Comment: Ugh, I meant to ask about `NE`. Which thing would otherwise be encoded twice?

Comment: Without `NE` there Apache will encode query string twice. First time while capturing text in `%0` and second time while redirecting (if `NE` is not present).

Comment: So it never makes sense to use B without NE then?

Comment: I would say it almost always makes sense to use `NE` flag (`B` or no `B`) when doing an external redirect using `R` flag.

Comment: My question was whether you would see a B without a NE, not an NE without a B.

Comment: Yes I understood your question. Let me answer:  `B` without `NE` - Can be used when doing internal rewrites. `B` with `NE` - Recommended when using `R` flag or doing an external redirect (i.e. URL changing in browser).